# Is there some way to get registered url schemes at iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uidocumentinteraction

I develops iOS application and want to interact with another application using `UIDocumentInteractionController` class or at least just open that application with `[UIApplication openUrl]` method.

But both methods requires url scheme that I don't know. Sites like http://handleopenurl.com/ doesn't contains information about needed application, and it hasn't interaction documentation, while some another applications successfully interacts with it.

Can I somehow get url schemes registered on device?

Comment: what applicatin are you trying to open ?

Comment: @Teja, I need Yandex Navigator. Our manager said that Uber application interacts with Yandex Navigator (at least calls routing). Yandex has API for maps and other applications, but hasn't for navigator :(

Comment: Search for yandexmaps and build_route_on_map -- there are some examples of that. Like this: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexmaps://build_route_on_map/?lat_from=59.967870&lon_from=30.242658&lat_to=59.898495&lon_to=30.299559"]];` -- maybe you'll find something related to what you need to do

Comment: Thanks Lou, due to your comment I found [documentation](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-ios) with url scheme (`yandexnavi://` instead `yandexmaps://`). One problem for non-russian developers - that documentation is in russian language.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably figure it out if you download the app onto your Mac and then examine it, but iOS recently locked down the ability to ask about available URL schemes.

To figure it out on your Mac you'd have to open the .ipa file (I believe it's just a zip archive, so you copy it and rename the copy to .zip), right click on the package, find the app, right-click on that, and open the info.plist file. In the info.plist file you'd want to look for a `CFBundleURLTypes` entry that tell the system which URL types the app handles.

Comment: This won't tell you the full URL you need, just the URL.scheme it uses.

Comment: That's correct. I think that's the best you're going to be able to do unless there is some other source of information.

Answer (score 0):

If the app made a URL scheme, then they probably want other developers to use it. Check their website to see if they document it -- if not, contact them.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

you can also get url schemes from the website's of applications through inspect elements if they provided. I found a solution for my app with this way for Facebook, youtube, etc:[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this site doesn't contain needed application too

Comment: try to find using inspect element from application site..! if your needed application has site..!